# what is the correct flow of elastic search display

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have thousands of articles in elastic-search server. i can search and get data now but the problem is i need to search articles with privacy for the logged in user.
 User can see an article if one of these 5 conditions.

1. Article is shared for all.
2. Article is shared to a group in which the user is member.
3. Article in directly shared to user.
4. @tagged user in comment description
5. @tagged user in article description.

now, how can i search for articles via elastic-search with privacy to a given user?

any ideas or recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shield for privacy.but it is paid service.If budget permits you can use it
https://www.elastic.co/products/shield